# insert multi arrays as serialize in to database

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 arrays with same name. I want to instert both in to same column after serialize. Please help me!

```
$pymntDtlsArray = array(
'description' => "package_name",
'amount' => 999,
'qty' => 1
);


$pymntDtlsArray = array(
'description' => "device_name",
'stb' => 1,
'unique_id' => 111,
'amount' => 0,
'qty' => 1
);

$register->details_array = serialize($pymntDtlsArray);
```

Comment: You couldn't declare same array name multiple times. Below one will override the above one array. If you want this whole data then must keep seperate keys for these both or use indexed array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json_encode() before saving, and save produced json in database, and when load data use json_decode().

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
$pymntDtlsArray = array(
    array(
        'description' => "package_name",
        'amount' => 999,
        'qty' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'description' => "device_name",
        'stb' => 1,
        'unique_id' => 111,
        'amount' => 0,
        'qty' => 1
    )
);
$register->details_array = serialize($pymntDtlsArray);
```